# Issue with trying to use Kmeans with Iris dataset from Seaborn

Tags: python, spyder

Hi I'm trying to figure out why this error message is coming up. I've looked at other things on here that are similar but the response for those ones aren't working for me. I'm using Spyder (python 3.8)

```
data = sns.load_dataset('iris', delimiter= ',')
X = normalize(data[:,1:],axis=0,norm='max')
Y = data[:,0]

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X2d = pca.fit_transform(X)
fig = plt.figure()
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
plt.scatter(X2d[:,0],X2d[:,1],c=Y,cmap=matplotlib.color.ListedColormap(colors))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Error Message:

```
data = sns.load_dataset('iris', delimiter= ',')
X = normalize(data[:,1:],axis=0,norm='max')
Y = data[:,0]
X = data.iloc[:,1:].values
Y = data.iloc[:,0].values
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X2d = pca.fit_transform(X)
fig = plt.figure()
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
plt.scatter(X2d[:,0],X2d[:,1],c=Y,cmap=matplotlib.color.ListedColormap(colors))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-3672f057e666>", line 2, in <module>
    X = normalize(data[:,1:],axis=0,norm='max')

  File "/Users/Faith/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "/Users/Faith/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Comment: `sns.load_dataset` returns a `pandas.DataFrame`, not a `numpy.ndarray`. You can [transform it](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html), though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still getting some errors but I'm trying to figure them out!

Comment: No problem, if you want you can update the question so we can try to solve them.

Comment: I just posted a new one I didn't realize I could update the question! But thank you for that! my new issue is with the TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable. Also I'm using a mac I think that can make a difference sometimes.